# Iterating through a list of resource values inside a list in a Terraform local

Tags: terraform

I am trying to get an array of arrays to use in a Terraform template_file data field:

```
data "template_file" "dashboard" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/files/dashboard.json")}"

  vars {
    metrics = "${jsonencode(local.metrics)}"
  }
}
```

But I am not finding the proper way to get what I want. I have an aws_instance resource with a count of 3, and I am trying to generate 3 arrays inside a local based on each one of the resource counts. The only thing I've come up with so far is:

```
locals {
  metrics = [
    "collectd", "GenericJMX.gauge.50thPercentile", "Host", "${aws_instance.instance.*.id}", "PluginInstance", "cassandra_client_request-latency"
  ]
}
```

Obviously what this does, is put all the instances one after the other in the same array. What I am trying to achieve is a result array that would look like:

```
["collectd", "GenericJMX.gauge.50thPercentile", "Host", "the id of instance 0", PluginInstance", "cassandra_client_request-latency"], 
["collectd", "GenericJMX.gauge.50thPercentile", "Host", "the id of instance 1", PluginInstance", "cassandra_client_request-latency"], 
["collectd", "GenericJMX.gauge.50thPercentile", "Host", "the id of instance 3", PluginInstance", "cassandra_client_request-latency"]
```

And this would be  expanded in the template ${metrics} variable.

Is there any way to achieve what I want, inside a local, and make it usable in the template?

Comment: I think you need this: https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/terraform-0-12-rich-value-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

terraform data source supports [count](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/pull/8635) as well.

It is a hide feature, and never be documented (https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/pull/8635)

Do some adjustments on your `dashboard.json`, then use below codes to generate number of template_file data source resources.

```
data "template_file" "dashboard" {
  count = "${length(aws_instance.instance.*.id)}"
  template = "${file("${path.module}/files/dashboard.json")}"

  vars {
    metrics = "${element(aws_instance.instance.*.id, count.index)}"
  }
}
```

You can reference it as terraform count resources

```
count = "${length(aws_instance.instance.*.id)}"

${data.template_file.dashboard.*.rendered[count.index]}"
```

Here are the full test data.

```
$ cat main.tf
data "aws_ami" "ubuntu" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-trusty-14.04-amd64-server-*"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }

  owners = ["099720109477"] # Canonical
}

resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
  count         = 2
  ami           = "${data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id}"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags = {
    Name = "HelloWorld"
  }
}


data "template_file" "dashboard" {
  count    = "${length(aws_instance.instance.*.id)}"
  template = "${file("${path.module}/files/dashboard.json")}"

  vars {
    metric = "${element(aws_instance.instance.*.id, count.index)}"
  }
}

output "aws_instances" {
  value = "${length(aws_instance.instance.*.id)}"
}

$ cat files/dashboard.json
["collectd", "GenericJMX.gauge.50thPercentile", "Host", "${metric}", PluginInstance", "cassandra_client_request-latency"]
```

After you apply the change, check the tfstate file, the data sources are

```
data.template_file.dashboard.0
data.template_file.dashboard.1
```

Sample tfstate:

```
            "data.template_file.dashboard.1": {
                "type": "template_file",
                "depends_on": [
                    "aws_instance.instance.*"
                ],
                "primary": {
                    "id": "8e05e7c115a8d482b9622a1eddf5ee1701b8cc4695da5ab9591899df5aeb703d",
                    "attributes": {
                        "id": "8e05e7c115a8d482b9622a1eddf5ee1701b8cc4695da5ab9591899df5aeb703d",
 # the date is here ==> "rendered": "[\"collectd\", \"GenericJMX.gauge.50thPercentile\", \"Host\", \"i-015961b744ff55da4\", PluginInstance\", \"cassandra_client_request-latency\"]\n",
                        "template": "[\"collectd\", \"GenericJMX.gauge.50thPercentile\", \"Host\", \"${metric}\", PluginInstance\", \"cassandra_client_request-latency\"]\n",
                        "vars.%": "1",
                        "vars.metric": "i-015961b744ff55da4"
                    },
                    "meta": {},
                    "tainted": false
                },
                "deposed": [],
                "provider": "provider.template"
            }
```